# unwanted subfolder when adding a git submodule

Tags: git, subdirectory, git-submodules

I am trying to add a git submodule. The submodule itself works without any problem but my question is about the created layout when adding the submodule.

I am adding a simple submodule called utils that only contains a file.

I am using this

```
git submodule add --force ssh://myserver/home/git_repositories/utils js/utils
```

because I want to add the submodule utils into the js/utils folder

the problem is that after doing this operation, inside of the js/utils folder i find another folder called utils, like js/utils/utils and there I find my javascript.

I want to have a layout like js/utils/ and here my javascript.

I have tried to eliminate the /utils in the git submodule add like

```
git submodule add --force ssh://myserver/home/git_repositories/utils js/
```

but then git yields

```
'js' already exists in the index
```

Do you know any way to avoid that secondary /utils?

Thanks a lot in advance!

prussian blue

Comment: do you want the `js` folder to empty except for this one directory `utils`? Does the submodule contain a folder named `utils`?

Comment: A submodule, as part of its definition within Git, is always a single complete directory, so that it (can) acts as a repository in its own right. That directory will then contain a .git sub-directory in the normal way that all repos have one.

Comment: Hi, the js has to have its subfolders, like js/lib, js/controllers, etc. What I want is to have /js/utils and not /js/utils/utils because the submodule creates the extra /utils. I want only js/utils and that /utils to be the submodule

Comment: Also, I have found that if I do git submodule add --force ssh://artcodee@a2s79.a2hosting.com:7822/home/artcodee/git_repositories/utils js when the js folder doesn't exist, then the layout is correct as the utils will be in /js/utils. The problem is that my js is not empty!

Answer (score 1):

I have found that the problem was in my original utils repo.

Apparently I forgot to do git init in that particular folder and therefore it was getting the parent as root level, thus creating that extra unwanted /utils

To solve this, I simply had to do git init inside of the utils folder, git add . , git commit and push. When pulling as a submodule, now it has the right layout!

My bad! Hope this helps someone and many thanks for your help guys.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. remove section for this subrepo from `.gitmodules` file;
2. remove section for this subrepo from `.git/config` file;
3. `git rm --cached submodule_path`;
4. `rm -rf submodule_path`